# Use find data attribute to add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-attributes

I am attempting to create a menu with unique data attributes attached to each navigation item.  On click I want that navigation item to find the section with the same attribute and add a class to it. This is the code I am using thus-far (it is part of a much larger script).

```
var $el = $( '#bl-main' ),
$sections = $el.children( 'section' ),
$navItems = $( 'nav > a' );   


$navItems.on( 'click', function( event ) {

$el.addClass( 'bl-expand-item' );
$navItems.find("[data-section='" + current + "']");
$sections.find("[data-section='" + $navItems + "']").addClass( 'expand expand-top' );
} );
```

This is the script it based off of. http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenLayoutPageTransitions/

The idea is to add a separate floating navigation to link to the different sections (instead of the direct click to expand that is current implemented). The current script I added only seems to refresh the page on click. I couldn't get it to work in a fiddle at all so the original script im sure will work. The section pasted about I have added in on my local files.

Comment: You forgot a dollarsign -> `var $section = $('section'),`

Comment: And that's why, a JavaScript developer should away's use the Chrome Developers Console or Firebug. I can't develop without those tools. They are so helpful for bugs.

Comment: and your question is.... ?

Answer (score 0):

On the first line, when you try to call for a `<section>` element, you are missing the jQuery shorthand before the parentheses. That should fix your script.

So it should look like:

```js
var $section = $('section');
```

That should have you all set to continue!

Answer (score 0):

First off you are missing your $ in the first variable assignment.  **var $section = $('section')**

After that it is difficult to tell what you're trying to do without seeing your markup, but I'll take a stab at it.

It appears that you are trying to filter the $section object by the data-section attribute of the nav > a element.  This code should do just that:

```
var $section = $( 'section' ), $navItems = $( 'nav > a' );   

$navItems.on( 'click', function( event ) {
    var $navSection = $section.filter("[data-section='" + $( this ).data( 'section' ) + "']");
    $navSection.addClass( 'expand expand-top' );
    return false;
} );
```

Notice that we are filtering all of the sections by the value of the clicked anchor's data-section attribute.

If that doesn't help, add your markup so we can see your structure.

Comment: I have updated the original post with the script used. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I cannot help further without seeing your html.  Please post that and I will help further.